# How to use the terminal tabs feature in mintty/MSYS2?

Tags: msys2, mintty

According to https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/944 since mintty 3.5.1 there should be a tab bar where you can open multiple tabs with terminals in parallel. For that reason I performed an installation of MSYS2 which includes mintty 3.5.1, as this seems to be the way how to use the mintty. (I verified this with invoking mintty with -V.)

However, I do not find no possibility for opening and/or managing tabs in the UI.

My requirement: I would very much like to have tabs for organizing terminals in parallel.

My question: What's going on here? Did I miss something? Do I need to execute the mintty/MSYS2 with some special commad line options? How can I enable tabs?

Answer (score 5):

It was difficult for me to figure out how to turn this feature on. The answer is sprinkled through the comments of [this issue](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/705), but not in one place. Therefore I'm posting this to save time for others. Here's how you turn the feature on:

Add `--tabbar=4` or `--tabbar` to the windows shortcut that opens mintty:

[image]

The `4` is [documented here](http://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html):

0. no geometry handling; terminal session windows are separate [default]
1. sync. position/size when switching/launching/closing a session
2. sync. also when window is moved or resized
3. sync. also when window is minimized
4. sync. also when window is started separately

If you'd like to create new tabs with `ctrl-shift-t`, close tabs with `ctrl-shift-w`, switch to previous tabs with `ctrl-shift-tab`, and switch to next tabs with `ctrl-tab`, add `-o "KeyFunctions=t:new-window-cwd;w:close"` as an option to that same line.

Personally, I'd like to have `ctrl-t/w` open and close tabs, respectively, but the only way I've figured how to do that is to add this option: `-o CtrlExchangeShift=yes`. The problem is, that changes *all* ctrl-shift commands to become ctrl commands. That means `ctrl-r` no longer searches bash history.

When you run the shortcut and create some tabs, mintty will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `--tabbar` option when staring minnty.  see [here](http://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html) for more information.

Comment: Doesn't work. I invoke "`mingw64.exe --tabbar`", I get a window for a quarter of a second and it closes immediately. A "`mingw64.exe --tabbar=1`" doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi @RegisMay, I create a desktop shortcut of mintty and set the Target: `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe --tabbar` in its property window. Do you invoke minnty the same way?

Comment: Hi John, I've installed MSYS2 which provides `mintty` 3.5.1 as well. But now I've additionally installed Cygwin and follwed your recommendation. Thank you for that!

Comment: However, it turns out that the "tabbar" implementation is quite useless. It seems that `mingw64` implements this by moving and resizing other windows. That means: There are still all the different windows with all the different icons in the windows taskbar, and the "tabbar" is nothing more than an overview about what other windows there are. No true "tabbing" such as having multiple views managed within a single window :-(

Comment: @RegisMay For my needs, that's not useless (though i wish it worked the way you wanted). Maybe with the shortcuts mentioned in my answer will make the situation livable.